# How can I change language of textbox in silverlight 4 at runtime?

Tags: c#, silverlight, silverlight-4.0

I have several textbox , what i want to do is some fields supposed to fill with for example Arabic and some with English , users of my webapps all have both languages added in windows keyboard i mention it cause it's not the problem !

I mean when users focused into some textbox control's the default language is changes to for example arabic.

Comment: I think this question has already been answered:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1865953/changing-the-ui-language-dynamically?tab=newest#tab-top